# Edited a file from GitHub, conflict in pushing?

Tags: git, github

This is my scenario:

Created and uploaded a project on GitHub. Did some commits *(ahead of origin/master by `n` commits)*. While viewing the repository on GitHub through web browser I found a minor error and can't control myself from fixing it using GitHub's very own code editor.

After coming to my local repository, what do I do now? I neither want to lose the changes from GitHub's editor nor want to loose changes that I had already commited.

*(I have single branch on that repository (master) and I am only the developer)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `git pull`, but I'd recommend doing a `git pull --rebase` as this will avoid having to have an additional merge commit joining the two development histories, thus keeping your history tidy.

Here's a bit of explanation on rebase pulls and how you can enable them by default: http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/11/git-pull-rebase-by-default/

Comment: +1 on this. Linear history is far more clear. (git config branch.autosetuprebase always)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a `git pull`, which fetches the changes from Github and merges the two heads.

If you look at the first graphic [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html), it explains a similar situation.